# Dividing the content of a multimedia playlist in two in an Android application

Tags: java, android, media

I was wondering how can a playlist which receives images and videos in a particular order display each different content type in two separate views and play it at the same time, side by side?

Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have the playlist as a data structure which is thread save.

Than you have one thread for each component and each thread than asks the playlist if there is something for it to do.

Another way would be to have one thread which controls the playlist and gives, depending on the content type, list entries to the component which can handle the content type. Like a plugin, every component is started as its own thread and registers itself and what type of content type it can play at the playlist controller thread.